# Is it possible to have two consecutive request in a single flow in Mulesoft 4?

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I have a flow that request two different apis

I tried it but got an error about a schema required fields, but when I tried to remove one request (either of the two), it will run successfully.
[image]

Comment: Hello, this question requires more information. If possible, please include the xml you're using. We don't know if they are GET, POST, etc. What mimeType are they expecting?

Comment: And details of the error.

Comment: What you intended to do with first request? you can wrap it in aynch or try blocks to get into next request

Comment: Both requests should work, if you name output of each request in a target variable Your second request isn't getting any required payload values either as query params or URI parameters. You can them process/analyse results of both outputs in dataweave